Convolution with Dirac comb
I am trying to understand convolutions with distributions involving sums of delta functions. Consider the Dirac comb $\text{Sha} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-n)$ and a function $f(x)$.
The convolution $(\text{Sha} * f)(x)$ is formally:
$$
\langle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(y-n), f(x-y) \rangle = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x-n)
$$
My question is about the interchange of sum and distributional pairing in this equation. Is this interchange something that needs to be justified, or does it simply follow directly from the definition of how delta functions act on test functions?
More precisely:

Is the equation $(\text{Sha} * f)(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x-n)$ simply the definition of how convolution with a sum of deltas works?
Or do we need to justify interchanging the sum and the distributional pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$?
\end{enumerate}

I would appreciate understanding this for both:
a. Nice functions $f$ (e.g., Schwartz class)
b. More general cases where $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x-n)$ is only locally integrable
The broader context is that I'm studying convolutions with weighted sums of delta functions, and I want to understand when we can write
$$
\left(\sum_{n} c_n \delta(x-a_n)\right) * f = \sum_{n} c_n f(x-a_n)
$$
without additional justification.

I'm not sure I understand your question, but perhaps you're asking how to justify evaluating $$\left\left(\sum_n \delta(y-n)\right) * f(y)\right=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_n \delta(y-n)\right) \cdot f(x-y) , dx$$ term-wise as $$\sum_n \left\left(\delta(y-n)\right) * f(y)\right=\sum_n \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(y-n) \cdot f(x-y) , dx=\sum_n f(x-n)$$ by interchanging the order of summation and integration?

@StevenClark Yes! perhaps i should have been more exact with the question. Is there a limiting argument that is generally used?

You are mixing way too many things in your question. I would suggest to start with a better understanding of what $\delta$ is, what the convolution with $\delta$ is, etc.
By definition, delta function $\delta_a$ is a linear continuous functional that returns the value $\varphi(a)$ on the test functions. $\delta_a$ is not a function, it is a distribution or generalized function. It is written often $\langle \delta_a,\varphi\rangle=\varphi(a)$. Now, what is a convolution of $\delta_a$ with a function (note, with a function, not a distribution, although it is possible, sometimes, define convolution of two distributions)?
By definition, $f\ast \delta_a$ is a distribution, which is defined through the equality
$$
\langle f\ast \delta_a,\varphi\rangle=\langle \delta_a, f^-\ast\varphi\rangle,
$$
where $f^-(x)=f(-x)$. Of course, to make sense out of it, one needs to check that $f^-\ast\varphi$ is again a test function. Note also that the result is the same as the distribution induced by $f(x-a)$, and therefore we write $f\ast \delta_a=f(x-a)$.
(A distribution induced by $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ is the functional defined by $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\varphi(x)dx$).
Now, what is the shah function $S=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\delta_k$? It is a distribution defined by
$$
\langle S,\varphi \rangle=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\varphi(k).
$$
It is a definition, and this definition makes perfect sense because $\varphi$ is from the Schwartz class, and the series $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\varphi(k)$ certainly converges. No need for any justification of "switching the order."
Now to the convolution with $S$. Going the same way, we define the convolution of $f\ast S$ as the distribution by the equality
$$
\langle f\ast S,\varphi\rangle=\langle S,f^-\ast \varphi\rangle,
$$
and it would be the distribution induced by $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(x-k)$ if
the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(x-k)$ converges tp some $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not. It certainly converges if $f$ has compact support (it is especially nice if ${\rm{supp}}\,\{f\}\subseteq (-1/2,1/2)$, it will be just a periodization with period one of the copies of the original $f$) or $f$ is from the Schwartz class itself, but in general it does not have to.

(+1) for the clear and concise post.  ;-)
